# Why can't I delete an OU from Powershell (when I can with another UI)?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I create an OU with:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create(
    "New-ADOrganizationalUnit $cn -path `"$path`" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion 0"
  )
    
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential `
    -ScriptBlock $sb
    
$dn = "OU=$cn,$path"
```

and then try to delete it with:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create(
    "Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit `"$dn`" -Recursive -Confirm:0"
  )

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Credential `
    -ScriptBlock $sb
```

And I get an "Access is denied" message

> Access is denied
>
> CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (...the DN...) [Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit], UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADOrganizationalUnit
>
> PSComputerName        : ...my server...

Note that when created I turned off protection from accidental deletion (which I can confirm on the domain controller).

I get the same access denied message if I pass the server and credentials to

```
Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Server $server -Credential $Credential "$dn" -Recursive -Confirm:0`
```

and if I open a remote session and run the `Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit` in that context.

The really odd part is that I can point LDAP-Admin at the same server with the *same credentials* and delete the OU just fine.  I can't explain the inconsistency.

I do see that the Effective Accesss on the newly-created object are not what I'd expect.  On the OU which is the parent of the OU I create, the user has

- Create/delete Group objects for this and all descendants
- Create/delete Organizational Unit objects for this and all descendants
- Create/delete User objects for this and all descendants
- Full control for Descendant Group objects
- Full control for Descendant User objects
- List contents for this and all descendants
- Read all properties for this and all descendants
- Write all properties for this and all descendants
- Read permissions for this and all descendants

But I lack Delete and Delete subtree on the OU I create.  Why isn't Created/delete OU inherited and why does LDAP-Admin work and PS doesn't?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is it isn't liking the `-Identity` you're passing in via the `$dn`. What if you run `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` then pipe that into the `Remove-` cmdlet? So something like `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "$dn" | Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that gives the same error.

Comment: Can you execute the commands using PowerShell remote session, instead of calling it with `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: @ShawnMelton, thanks for the suggestion but that fails, too.

Comment: If it fails executing via remote session that means if you logged into the server it would fail as well. You have a permissions issue on the remote server, or with the using the AD PowerShell module itself. The `LDAP-Admin` is not going to use the PowerShell AD module to perform the task so it is not really any oddity about that working.

Comment: I don't agree about it not being odd.  To recap: using the same user name and password to connect via LDAP-Admin and various PS mechanisms (`Invoke-Command`, remove session, passing server and cred to `Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit`), LDAP Admin succeeds and PS fails.  Why isn't it odd that the same credentials work on one channel but not on another? Especially when the error ("access denied")  seems to be about permissions/credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After revising the question to itemize permissions, Rubber Duck Debugging reveals that the list is inconsistent in that it lacks "Full control for Descendant Organizational Unit objects."  I maintain that it shouldn't be necessary with the create/delete permissions I have and I'm baffled by the inconsistency between PS and LDAP-Admin.  However, adding that Full control permission solves the problem and is an acceptable workaround for the odd inheritance or my misunderstanding of AD.